# How not to hard code Boto3 client credentials in to Python3 / Kivy script

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, kivy, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to hide the credentials to my boto3 client situated in a kivy app (python3). The boto3 is being used for SecretsManager to hold other credentials for RDS db access.

```
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
        aws_access_key_id='AK########.....'
```

I don't want to hard code my access key, secret etc

I've thought about assigning a specific `IAM` role to this client which would in theory give me the role/access required to boto3 but don't know exactly how to go about this.

I also use cognito for login (auth); I could possibly set up a group which is attached to these users and then get the creds/access to the boto3 client via this (which I think would work).

Is there a better solution to this or is my workflow all wrong?!

Many thanks!

Comment: If your client run on EC2 (or Lambda or ECS) then it's trivial to launch the compute with an IAM role that will allow the boto3 SDK to retrieve credentials seamlessly.

Comment: No it doesn't. Kivy is python framework for android and ios

Comment: Python on mobile, who knew? Typical mobile pattern is to use Amplify or Cognito. Because you're using Python (rather than JS, Swift, or Java) you'll likely have to go with Cognito, assuming you don't want to build your own server-side code to vend credentials or to proxy your access to AWS resources.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to hardcoding your Access Key ID and Secret Access Key would be to use Amazon Cognito Identity Pools, which generate roles with a set of permissions. I would recommend you to look into the [GetId](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_id) and [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_credentials_for_identity) API calls in Boto3.

Comment: This is what I thought to do. I'll have a read and test some code. Can I ask if I get stuck?

Comment: Sure. You could ask a new question with eloquent details, and let me know.

Comment: I can GetID and GetCredentialsForIdentity for the IdentityID I retrieve for an Identity. The access key and secret key that returns keeps `GetSecretValue operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.` . The permissions for the role are exactly the same as for another IAM user which has access when the access key/sec key are hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials), there are multiple ways to do so, you could read from environment variables, file, shared file config (the .aws/credentials file...).

I would recommend using a secret from a [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) to get those keys.

If you're looking for a fast way, using the shared creds (item 4) inside the host would not be a big problem (IMO).

If any problem occurs, you just disable those creds and generate a new one.